# Python Tkinter Window and Widget Size Measurements

Tags: python, tkinter, size, measurement

Does anyone know in what units are the measurements made in tkinter objects?

For example:

```
ws='400' #i am assuming these are in pixels
hs='400'
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry(ws+'x'+hs)
```

...

```
self.w1=tk.Label(self.parent,width=int(int(ws)*5/8) #The width here probably isn't in pixels
self.w2=tk.Button(self.parent,width=int(int(ws)*3/8)
```

If the width in the widgets Label and Button were also measured in pixels, this should fit them nicely within the window, regardless of its width. But it doesn't. Instead, i experimented and found that dividing the width by 10 for one widget and 25 for the other does the trick.
So in what units is either of these measured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the widget, and also on how the widget is configured. For `Label` and `Button` widgets the `width` and `height` refer to a number of average sized characters (internally, I believe it uses the width and height of the character zero). If you add an image to the label or button, the width refers to a number of pixels.

You will usually get the best results by avoiding hard-coding pixel values. Tkinter is really good about computing the appropriate size for widgets, and then fitting them into the window.

Comment: like @bryan oakley said! some are pixels other are relative

Comment: I did the calculus, turns out 1 pixel equals 0.14 characters, and 1 character equals 7.1 pixels. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Akenaten: different fonts have different sizes. Plus, if you're using a variable width font, some characters take up less space than others. For example, the letter "i" will require fewer pixels than the letter "m".

Comment: @BryanOakley Maybe, but i tried it with a blank Label element. So i guess the values i gave above should be true for the default character font/size that the label uses.

Comment: @Akenaten: it will be true for your specific computer configuration. It may not be true on other machines, and it almost certainly won't be true if you switch font families or font sizes.